# SELECT com duas foreign key, retornar as duas tabelas mesmo procurando apenas uma das chaves

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query

Eu possuo uma tabela que possui duas FK para referenciar uma mesma tabela.
Ao selecionar todos os elementos que possui uma das duas FK, utilizando a query:

```
SELECT "Proposta".id, "Proposta".id_segurado, "Proposta".data_implantacao, "Proposta".data_assinatura, "Proposta".status,
"Segurado".documento, "Segurado".nome,
"Produtor".id, "Produtor".nome, "Produtor".codigo, "Produtor".documento
FROM "Proposta"
LEFT JOIN "Segurado" ON "Proposta".id_segurado = "Segurado".id
LEFT JOIN "Produtor" ON "Produtor".id = "Proposta".id_produtor1 OR "Produtor".id = "Proposta".id_produtor2
```

Recebo os dados das duas FKs, porém ao fazer um WHERE para achar uma proposta para achar o produtor que possui aquele documento, recebo os dados apenas de uma das FKs e não dos dois como antes, como faria para receber ambos os dados?

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta. Tente postar um exemplo do que você diz ser o retorno antes (que teria dado certo) e o que deu errado, lembrando que você está utilizando LEFT OUTER JOIN e não INNER JOIN e portanto é normal não existir dados da tabela "Segurado" e/ou da tabela "Produtor".

Comment: Quando eu executo a query sem o WHERE ela me retorna duas linhas para cada proposta, sendo a unica diferença os dados dos produtores. Caso eu coloque um WHERE por exemplo "Produto".codigo = '35125' ele retorna a proposta somento com o dado desse produtor e não traz o os dados do segundo id_produtor2

Comment: Creio que você está se confundindo. Se sua proposta pode estar relacionada a dois produtores (identificados pelos campos id_produtor1 e  id_produtor2 de sua tabela "Proposta") então você precisa fazer um LEFT OUTER JOIN com a tabela "Produtor" no papel de produtor1 e outro LEFT OUTER JOIN com a mesma tabela "Produtor" mas agora no papel de produtor2.

Comment: Testei usando o LEFT OUTER JOIN e o resultado foi o mesmo. A questão é que ao usar um WHERE, no final, ele retorna os dados apenas de um Produtor e não de ambos.

SELECT ...
FROM "Proposta"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Segurado" ON "Proposta".id_segurado = "Segurado".id
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Produtor" ON "Produtor".id = "Proposta".id_produtor1 OR "Produtor".id = "Proposta".id_produtor2
WHERE "Produtor".codigo = '8002866'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelas suas explicações que que o que deseja é:

```
SELECT  "Proposta".id,  "Proposta".id_segurado, "Proposta".data_implantacao, "Proposta".data_assinatura, "Proposta".status,
            "Segurado".documento, "Segurado".nome,
            p1.id, p1.nome, p1.codigo, p1.documento, p2.id, 
            p2.nome, p2.codigo, p2.documento
FROM "Proposta"
LEFT JOIN "Segurado" ON "Proposta".id_segurado = "Segurado".id
LEFT JOIN "Produtor" p1 ON p1.id = "Proposta".id_produtor1
LEFT JOIN "Produtor" p2 ON p2.id = "Proposta".id_produtor2
```

Ou seja "Produtor" participando da query com dois papéis.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, no final eu só usei um WHERE para procurar o dado específico.
Muito obrigado, sua resposta foi de grande ajuda!